# Reposting data through a generic method that is independent of form model in ASP MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

This is the client's request: in some cases there are several forms that don't require authentication or it takes too long for a logged user to finish completing a form and the session expires. In theses cases he wants to retain the data when the user submits the form by serializing and storing it in a SQL table and then, after the user (re)logs in, he is redirected to the respective form and that is repopulated with the data retrieved from the database and deserialized.

The problem is that he wants all the logic of the storing, retrieving and resending the data in the authorization code block. I know how to do the storing, serialization, retrieving, deserialization of data and the user redirection to the respective page, but I don't know hoe to make it generic so that it works for every model on every form.

The client does not want any code for this task done in the form action method. For example:

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Create(Post post)
{
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
post.CreatedBy = (Guid)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;
post.CreateTime = DateTime.Now;

repo.Add(post);
repo.Save();

return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
else
{
return View(post);
}
}
```

As you can see he wants to keep it as clean as possible. He had this suggestion:

> The server receives a HTTP request in RAW text format. Using this text, it builds the objects (RequestContext, FormCollection collection, etc. etc.). So, you should be able to build in a hook and e.g. save the raw request. After succesfull login, this previous raw text of the HTTP request could be injected in the handling.

I don't really know how to do that or even if it is possible in MVC.
If someone can help I'll be extremely grateful.

Thanks,
ABTeam

Comment: Why is the client specifying implementation details?  Is there requirement in the requirements document for this?

Comment: The real question is, why isn't your client paying us instead of you? ;)

Comment: He already has the application and all he wants is that custom authorization part and he probably got the implementation suggestion from another application (done in php I think) in which something similar was done. There is no such thing as a requirements document as this is a subcontracting job.

Answer (score 2):

The proper way to do this is to capture the user's progress in the database, and provide a mechanism for returning them to the next step in the process.  This can be done with a `?step=n` parameter in the URL.  If the user gets logged off, they can log back in and be returned to the correct step in the process.

Your client's request for doing this in the authorization code block is not an appropriate use of functionality.  That's not the purpose of the authorization block, and attempting to do business logic there, in the manner that the client describes, will almost certainly compromise security and result in unmaintainable code.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't see how this would help me. There aren't necessarily wizard-type linked forms so that I could use a step parameter and even so, how could I repopulate the form with that? I repeat, it's not that I can't redirect to the correct form after the user logs back in, the problem is that I don't know how to pass the data from the database back to the form in a generic way that is independent of the used model. I hope I didn't misunderstand your answer, but if I did please provide some more detail. Anyway, I agree that this should not be done in the authorization block.

Answer (score 0):

The authorization block is not the right place for it, but you may be able to do something fairly generic with action filters.

Load the saved data in OnActionExecuting. I'm not sure if you'll be able to get it passed to the action method as a parameter, but at the least you should be able to add it into ViewData so it can be used as a starting point for generating the model for the form page.

Not sure if the model will be available for saving before ActionExecuting, but if not the model as it exists after the action method runs should be an appropriate alternative.

Comment: I can't use ViewData as it would mean that I have to process the data in the form and the client does not want that. For instance, take the action code block I provided. Regarding the issue, the code should not be changed (the client was specific about this). The post parameter should have value when the user resubmits the form after he logs back in. Thus, the form has to be populated after he is redirected so that when it is resubmitted, the post parameter has the intended value.